singularity and velocity
I recently read article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03262 "A new approach to computing the asymptotics of the position of Fisher-KPP fronts"
the author consider
$$ \begin{equation*}
    \varphi(r,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}[h(\mu_t+z,t)]^2\exp(rz) dz
\end{equation*}$$
$$ 
\begin{equation*}
\Psi(r)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d} x h_{0}(x) e^{r x} \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
$$
then the authors proved that :
$$
\begin{equation*}
\Psi(r)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} t \varphi(r, t) e^{r \mu_{t}-\left(r^{2}+1\right) t} \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
$$
i have two question :
first why  that $\varphi(r, t) e^{r \mu_{t}}$ is independent of $\mu_{t}$.?
second question
in the  section 5, they  mentioned: "if $h_0$ decays as"$exp(-\gamma x)$ and When $ r < \gamma <<1$, but the authors says that the integral in (5) converges because $r\mu_{t} - (r^{2} + 1) t )$ goes to $-\infty $ linearly in $\( t \)$." However, I thought that this could also be deduced directly from equation $(4)$
However, I realize that this convergence might not be immediately evident, given that the behavior of $\mu_{t}$ is not yet determined and i think that is  the aim of this section. Could you clarify this point?
Thank you very much for your assistance and attention to this matter.

To answer your first point, note that for the definition of $\varphi(r,t)$, the integral is taken over $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, the integral does not change when you substitute the dummy variable $z$ with $z-\mu_t$. Doing this substitution replaces $\exp(rz)$ with $\exp(r(z-\mu_t))$, hence you can pull $\exp(-r\mu_t)$ out of the integral which cancells with the $\exp(r\mu_t)$. The remaining integral is now independent of $\mu_t$.
For your second point, I think you are completely right that if this were a math paper starting from first principles, you can't assume all that the authors assume. However, the authors know everything there is to know about F-KPP and hence use a priori that $\mu_t/t\to v$. Furthermore, this is physics, not math, and therefore heuristics about the convergence of integrals are enough to constitute a proof.
